# Android Studio JaCoCo test coverage multiple Android modules

Tags: android, testing, code-coverage, jacoco

I am running Android Studio 2.2 and created a new application, added an Android library module to it.

To enable test coverage I have added tag `testCoverageEnabled true` in `buildTypes`. Now if I run `gradle createDebugCoverageReport` then I am able to get code coverage. Also I can create coverage report separately for library module by using command `gradle lib_module:createDebugCoverageReport`.

Now if I add a flavor with name `flavor` to this project then the commands should be modified as

```
gradle createFlavorDebugCoverageReport
gradle lib_module:createFlavorDebugCoverageReport
```

With flavors I am not able to generate code coverage report. Build fails with `IncompatibleClassType` error .

1. Following is the *build.gradle* for module `app`

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.piyush.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
   }
   productFlavors {
        flavor {
        }
   }
   }

   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
      compile project(':mylibrary')
   }
   ```
2. Following is the *build.gradle* for library module `mylibrary`

   ```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        flavor {
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    }
   ```